# CSS positioning glitch with inline-block elements

Tags: html, css

Please consider the following code snippet.

My question is: why is the second li, the one with class `filterdivision`, lower in the layout than the previous one instead of being verticaly aligned with it ? I gave it the same height and see no margin or padding that might push it down.

Javascript code isn't relevant to the question but allows the snippet to be functional.

```js
var triggerFilter = function(filterData)
{
 console.log(filterData);
}

$(".customDropdown li").on('click',function(){
    var $self = $(this);
    var $list = $self.parent();
    if($list.hasClass("listVisible"))
    { //Whole list is visible => Selecting an option 
     $list.find('.active').removeClass("active");
        $self.addClass("active");
        $list.removeClass("listVisible");
        triggerFilter({filterName:$list.data("fieldname"),filterValue:$self.data("fieldvalue")});
    }
    else
    {
        //Show whole list
     $list.addClass("listVisible");
    }
 
});
```

```css
.wrapper { background: #f2f2f2;; padding: 20px;position: relative;height:60px;}
.wrapper input { box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid #c2c2c2; font-size: 14px; padding: 10px 15px; width: 100%;}
.wrapper ol.filters { padding:0; margin: 0; font-size: 0; height:58px;}
.wrapper ol.filters > li
{
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 150px;
 margin-right:20px;
 height: 58px;/*Need to fix height because of absolute positionned fake dropdowns*/
 position:relative;
}

.wrapper ol.filters > li:last-child{ margin-right:0;}
.wrapper ol.filters > li:first-child{ width: 150px;}
.wrapper label { display:block; font-size:12px; color: #797979; margin-bottom: 3px;}

/* CSS for custom dropdown */
.customDropdown {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 50;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:150px;
}
.customDropdown li {display:none;padding: 10px 15px;font-size:14px;}
.customDropdown li::after { position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px; content: ""; display: inline-block; width: 0.5em; height: 0.5em; border-right: 2px solid black; border-bottom: 2px solid black; transform: rotate(45deg);}

.customDropdown li.active {display:block;}
.customDropdown.listVisible li {display:block;border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;}
.customDropdown.listVisible li:hover {background: #f2f2f2;color:#4fbbeb;}
.customDropdown.listVisible li.active {color:#4fbbeb;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
   <ol class="filters">
       <li class="filterSearch">
           <label for="filterSearch">Search</label><input type="text" id="search">
       </li>
       <li class="filterDivision">
           <label>Division</label>
           <ol class="customDropdown" data-fieldname="division">
               <li class="active" data-fieldvalue="all">All divisions</li>
               <li data-fieldvalue="consulting">Consulting</li>
               <li data-fieldvalue="digital">Digital</li>
               <li data-fieldvalue="other">Other</li>
           </ol>
       </li>
       <!-- ... Other filter options in li tags -->
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
float:left
```

instead of

```
display:inline-block
```

in

```
.wrapper ol.filters > li
```

Although this doesn't seem to be an issue here, floating elements wont affect the parent elements height, unless you add

```
clear:both;
overflow:auto;
```

to the parent elements style like this:

```
<div style="clear:both; overflow:auto">
     <div style="float:left">hello</div>
     <div style="float:left">world</div>
</div>
```

here's you code snippet using floating elements (I'm not sure what's causing your issue exactly, but floating left fixes it)

```js
var triggerFilter = function(filterData)
{
 console.log(filterData);
}

$(".customDropdown li").on('click',function(){
    var $self = $(this);
    var $list = $self.parent();
    if($list.hasClass("listVisible"))
    { //Whole list is visible => Selecting an option 
     $list.find('.active').removeClass("active");
        $self.addClass("active");
        $list.removeClass("listVisible");
        triggerFilter({filterName:$list.data("fieldname"),filterValue:$self.data("fieldvalue")});
    }
    else
    {
        //Show whole list
     $list.addClass("listVisible");
    }
 
});
```

```css
.wrapper { background: #f2f2f2;; padding: 20px;position: relative;height:60px;}
.wrapper input { box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid #c2c2c2; font-size: 14px; padding: 10px 15px; width: 100%;}
.wrapper ol.filters { padding:0; margin: 0; font-size: 0; height:58px;}
.wrapper ol.filters > li
{
 list-style-type: none;
    float:left;
 width: 150px;
 margin-right:20px;
 height: 58px;/*Need to fix height because of absolute positionned fake dropdowns*/
 position:relative;
}

.wrapper ol.filters > li:last-child{ margin-right:0;}
.wrapper ol.filters > li:first-child{ width: 150px;}
.wrapper label { display:block; font-size:12px; color: #797979; margin-bottom: 3px;}

/* CSS for custom dropdown */
.customDropdown {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 50;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:150px;
}
.customDropdown li {display:none;padding: 10px 15px;font-size:14px;}
.customDropdown li::after { position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px; content: ""; display: inline-block; width: 0.5em; height: 0.5em; border-right: 2px solid black; border-bottom: 2px solid black; transform: rotate(45deg);}

.customDropdown li.active {display:block;}
.customDropdown.listVisible li {display:block;border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;}
.customDropdown.listVisible li:hover {background: #f2f2f2;color:#4fbbeb;}
.customDropdown.listVisible li.active {color:#4fbbeb;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
   <ol class="filters">
       <li class="filterSearch">
           <label for="filterSearch">Search</label><input type="text" id="search">
       </li>
       <li class="filterDivision">
           <label>Division</label>
           <ol class="customDropdown" data-fieldname="division">
               <li class="active" data-fieldvalue="all">All divisions</li>
               <li data-fieldvalue="consulting">Consulting</li>
               <li data-fieldvalue="digital">Digital</li>
               <li data-fieldvalue="other">Other</li>
           </ol>
       </li>
       <!-- ... Other filter options in li tags -->
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: duh ! Stupid me for not even thinking about testing floats in this case. It indeed does the trick, without side effect as soon as I clear the float! Seeing this I'm thinking this might be some kind of line-height issue but hey, I've been wasting enough time on this already, it works, that's all I want, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inline blocks are blocks that try to span the entire width and in your code, the `.wrapper` didn't have the width set, which forced it to take up space beside, and not below

```js
var triggerFilter = function(filterData)
{
 console.log(filterData);
}

$(".customDropdown li").on('click',function(){
    var $self = $(this);
    var $list = $self.parent();
    if($list.hasClass("listVisible"))
    { //Whole list is visible => Selecting an option 
     $list.find('.active').removeClass("active");
        $self.addClass("active");
        $list.removeClass("listVisible");
        triggerFilter({filterName:$list.data("fieldname"),filterValue:$self.data("fieldvalue")});
    }
    else
    {
        //Show whole list
     $list.addClass("listVisible");
    }
 
});
```

```css
.wrapper { background: #f2f2f2;; padding: 20px;position: relative;height:150px; width: 60px}
.wrapper input { box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid #c2c2c2; font-size: 14px; padding: 10px 15px; width: 100%;}
.wrapper ol.filters { padding:0; margin: 0; font-size: 0; height:116px;}
.wrapper ol.filters > li
{
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
 margin-right:20px;
 height: 58px;/*Need to fix height because of absolute positionned fake dropdowns*/
 position:relative;
}

.wrapper ol.filters > li:last-child{ margin-right:0;}
.wrapper ol.filters > li:first-child{ width: 150px;}
.wrapper label { display:inline-block; font-size:12px; color: #797979; margin-bottom: 3px;}

/* CSS for custom dropdown */
.customDropdown {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 50;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:150px;
}
.customDropdown li {display:none;padding: 10px 15px;font-size:14px;}
.customDropdown li::after { position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px; content: ""; display: inline-block; width: 0.5em; height: 0.5em; border-right: 2px solid black; border-bottom: 2px solid black; transform: rotate(45deg);}

.customDropdown li.active {display:block;}
.customDropdown.listVisible li {display:block;border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;}
.customDropdown.listVisible li:hover {background: #f2f2f2;color:#4fbbeb;}
.customDropdown.listVisible li.active {color:#4fbbeb;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
   <ol class="filters">
       <li class="filterSearch">
           <label for="filterSearch">Search</label><input type="text" id="search">
       </li>
       <li class="filterDivision">
           <label>Division</label>
           <ol class="customDropdown" data-fieldname="division">
               <li class="active" data-fieldvalue="all">All divisions</li>
               <li data-fieldvalue="consulting">Consulting</li>
               <li data-fieldvalue="digital">Digital</li>
               <li data-fieldvalue="other">Other</li>
           </ol>
       </li>
       <!-- ... Other filter options in li tags -->
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't do what I want. i want these fields to appear side by side, vertically aligned, not on top of each other, else I wouldn't have changed the display property of `li`, being block by default they would appear one below each other... but thanks for looking at my question :-)